# 2016 Fort McMurray Wildfire Aerial Street Level Images with Exif GIS

Tags: geospatial, images, fire

In 2016 there was wildfire in Alberta, Canada that damaged property in Fort McMurray.  There are many images of damage to neighbourhoods on the internet like the one below. However, I have not been successful in finding images with [Exif GIS metadata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif).

I am looking for as many of the fields as possible as I want to as accurately as possible overlay lat/longs on the image for further processing. These depend on the camera's position, altitude, zoom, angle and other parameters.

I have a strong preference for a free resource as this is a hobbyist project at the moment.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have you contact GIS people at the city department in Fort McMurray about it ? They may help you how or where to find them ?

or go here http://www.rmwb.ca/living/Maps.htm . I am not sure of the province or city where they located is. I am from the United States, so not sure. You can do google if you have not done yet.